# HERE Maps: Give directions to correct side of the street

Tags: android, here-api

Occasionally when calculating a route it seems the vehicle ends being directed to the wrong side of the street.

I realize we can specify pass through waypoints before the final destination. This really isn't an option for us since we don't know from which direction the vehicle will be coming from.

Is there an alternative way to do this?

EDIT: I was told the issue occurred with these two lat/lons.

Start Location: 42.343763, -71.115977
End Location: 42.342545, -71.121875

EDIT: removed fragment sentence.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of this?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at the route and I'm not entirely clear on what the problem is. Is it that when you reach the destination, the car is on the right side of the street, but the destination is on the left side?

Comment: Yup since we are dealing with bus stop we care about the side of the street we end up on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NavigationWaypointParameter](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html) with LinkPositions to set a direction you want to drive through a certain waypoint. For example:

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?
app_code={app_code}
&app_id={app_id}
&mode=fastest;car
&waypoint0=link!-22020941
&waypoint1=link!-948669856
```

This should give you the route you are looking for, with the bus heading towards the south-east with the destination on its right.

[image: Arrival heading south-east]

You can change the direction of the link traversal by changing it's prefix. For example, changing `-948669856` to `+948669856` gives you the original, shorter route, with the bus heading north-west and the destination on the left side of the road.

[image: Arrival heading north-west]

Note that you can get the link ids through reverse geocoding using the [Geocoder API](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/examples-reverse-geocoding.html). The link id is the `<ReferenceID>` under `<MapReference>` in the `<Result>`.

Comment: Hmm...doesn't look like that is exposed in the Android SDK. Do you know offhand?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like only geo coordinates are supported in the SDK, so you may have to call the REST API.