# Waypoint heading works only on the first waypoint

Tags: here-api, direction, heading

I'm trying to get a route which obeys heading information provided in waypoints. It seems like only the first waypoint's heading influences the route geometry.

For example:

```
"https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json" \
"?app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx" \
"&waypoint0=geo!49.010830,8.417029;;;90" \
"&waypoint1=passThrough!49.011843,8.418113;;;180" \
"&waypoint2=geo!49.010020,8.419840;;;240" \
"&mode=shortest;car;traffic:disabled" \
"&routeattributes=wp,sm,sh"
```

[screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKapW.jpg)

returns a route with the second waypoint passed from south to north, even though it should be the opposite. The same for the last waypoint. The geometry of the route changes only when changing the first heading.

The same happens for the matrix request. Only the starting point's heading influences the distance.

I've seen a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425087/here-maps-give-directions-to-correct-side-of-the-street), but it makes things complicated, as I should make route requests for hundreds of waypoints, and therefore it is impossible to check all the prefixes manually.

Is there a way to solve my problem using the routing API? Or maybe I need a different API?

Answer (score 0):

180 degree turns are allowed for stopOver but not for passThrough.

[image]

```
 var router = platform.getRoutingService(),
    routeRequestParams = {
      mode: 'shortest;car;traffic:disabled',
      representation: 'display',
      routeattributes : 'waypoints,summary,shape,legs',
      maneuverattributes: 'direction,action',
      waypoint0: 'geo!49.010830,8.417029;;;90', // Brandenburg Gate
      waypoint1: 'stopOver!49.011843,8.418113;;;180',  // Friedrichstraße Railway Station
      waypoint2: 'geo!49.010020,8.419840;;;240'
    };
```

Comment: I don't need stopOvers. I need passThroughs in a given direction. I want my route to be something like this:
- start at 49.010830,8.417029 and head east
-> go to 49.011843,8.418113 and pass the waypoint from south to north
-> go to 49.010020,8.419840 and arrive at the destination from the east side.
Is it possible?

Comment: can you do this with more than 3 waypoints? or you have specific 3 waypoints ?

Comment: https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx&waypoint0=geo!49.010830,8.417029;;;90&waypoint1=passThrough!49.011843,8.418113;;;180&waypoint2=passThrough!49.010559,8.421295;;;240&waypoint3=geo!49.010329,8.423421;;;0&mode=shortest;car;traffic:disabled&routeattributes=wp,sm,sh
Still gives a wrong (for my understanding) result. Waypoint1 should be passed from north to south, waypoint 2 from east to west, waypoint 3 from south to north. Only the first waypoint's heading influences the route.